# How to save captured picture in kivy without timestamp as name

Tags: python, kivy

This is camera code

```
Camera Example
==============

This example demonstrates a simple use of the camera. It shows a window with
a buttoned labelled 'play' to turn the camera on and off. Note that
not finding a camera, perhaps because gstreamer is not installed, will
throw an exception during the kv language processing.

'''

# Uncomment these lines to see all the messages
# from kivy.logger import Logger
# import logging
# Logger.setLevel(logging.TRACE)

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (640, 480)
        play: False
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: camera.play = not camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()
''')


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def capture(self):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        #timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        camera.export_to_png("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

I want to save captured image in my current directory with a name like img.png instead of saving image name with a timestamp.
This code saves image with name like IMG_20200216_162830 and I want it like IMG.png
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the timestamp, that's all:

```
camera.export_to_png("IMG.png")
```

Comment: I tried it but it just does not respond and image is not captured

Comment: yes,it worked maybe I did a mistake last time while trying.Thank you!